# Signing Word, Excel By Users Without Docusign Account

Tags: excel, ms-word, docusignapi, account

Is it possible to sign a Microsoft word or excel document by a user without having Docusign account(embedded signing ceremony)? Can we download the signed document later in the same format(.doc or .xlsx) using API?

Comment: Welcome StackOverflow. Please CHECK the best answer to your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re:

> Is it possible to sign a Microsoft word or excel document by a user without having Docusign account(embedded signing ceremony)?

The signer does not need an account. But the sender, the person initiating the signing request does need a DocuSign account.

Re:

> Can we download the signed document later in the same format(.doc or .xlsx) using API?

The regular DocuSign eSignature service changes all source files, including Word and Excel files to the PDF format before they are signed.

DocuSign offers the [DocuSign Signature Appliance](https://www.docusign.com/products/hybrid-cloud-appliances) which can digitally sign Word and Excel files in their native format. The result is a signed Word/Excel file which can still be used as a Word/Excel file. But any changes invalidate the digital signature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. (in e signature, not in DSA)So it will take an excel/word as input document convert it into pdf, open the converted pdf in the embedded signing UI, user will sign in on the converted pdf, will be saved as pdf in the cloud and later it will be downloaded as pdf via API. Please confirm the flow if my understanding is right.

Answer (score 0):

First question:
If you build an integration for someone else - they wouldn't need to have an account. Someone (you, your customer, etc.) would have to have an account, but not every signer.

Second question:
The complete document is only available as PDF. You can convert it to some other format, but I'm not sure the reason you need it. The idea is that end-users can't easily modify that document,  as you wouldn't want someone to sign something and than you changed what they signed, right?